# ffmpeg chorus filter error: At least one output file must be specified

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I tried following command-line, but getting error:

> At least one output file must be specified

It runs ok when I removed "|"

`ffmpeg -i input.wav -af chorus=0.5:0.9:50|60|40:0.4|0.32|0.3:0.25|0.4|0.3:2|2.3|1.3 output.wav`

Answer (score 1):

The `|` character is used for piping i.e. sending the output of one command to another. So, when a command with that character has to be used, it should be inside quotes.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "chorus=0.5:0.9:50|60|40:0.4|0.32|0.3:0.25|0.4|0.3:2|2.3|1.3" output.wav
```